# Error in compiling more than one jar file with more than one java source files

Tags: java, compilation

I am attempting to compile 2 jar files and 4 java source files using the following command:

> javac -classpath junit-4.12.jar jar2.jar 1.java 2.java 3.java 4.java

However, I get the following error:

> error: package jar2 does not exist import jar2.class;

Although, the following compilation is successful:

> javac -classpath jar2.jar 1.java 2.java

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to assist me.

Comment: Is it in windows?

Comment: @javaguy No, it's on macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javac -classpath junit-4.12.jar jar2.jar 1.java 2.java 3.java 4.java
```

You don't use a valid separator between the values of the classpath.
A whitespace character is indeed not a valid separator for classpath values.

According to the OS based, the separator is either `:` or `;`.

With Unix OS based, the separator is `:` character ([see Oracle Java 8 reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html) ) :

```
  javac -classpath junit-4.12.jar:jar2.jar 1.java 2.java 3.java 4.java
```

With Windows OS based, the separator is `;` character ([see Oracle Java 8 reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html))  :

```
  javac -classpath junit-4.12.jar;jar2.jar 1.java 2.java 3.java 4.java
```

Comment: you are welcome :) It is nothing. I added a Oracle refernce about it on windows and unix os in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:` as file separator in between jars to set classpath for MacOS:

```
javac -classpath junit-4.12.jar:jar2.jar 1.java 2.java 3.java 4.java
```

Comment: I got it working. Thank you very much for the assistance.